# Pandas groupby methods returns no duplicate pairs but duplicates() method return duplicates in the same dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a some csv files contains information about data tables in my server

```
names= ('typ','nam_tbl','cod_tbl','nam_entry','cod_entry','desc','strong')
df_1=pd.read_csv('F4.csv',usecols=list(range(1,8)),names=names,skiprows=1)
df=pd.read_csv('F3.csv',usecols=list(range(1,8)),header=None,names=names)
```

Now I want to check if there is duplicated cod_tbl and cod_entry pairs, I tried groupby first

```
gp=df.groupby(['cod_tbl','cod_entry']).filter(lambda x:len(x)<1)
print(gp)
```

this approach returns an empty dataframe

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [typ, nam_tbl, cod_tbl, nam_entry, cod_entry, desc, strong]
Index: []
```

then I tried the duplicates() methods of pandas

```
print(df.duplicated(subset=['cod_tbl','cod_entry']))
```

the second methods returns some **True** values

```
0       False
1       False
2       False
3       False
4       False
        ...  
2702     True
2703     True
2704    False
2705     True
2706     True
Length: 2707, dtype: bool
```

I wonder why this two approaches may return contrary result, and how to avoid this problem

Answer (score 2):

*Did you mean* `len(x)>1` ?

Because with `len(x)<1`, you're asking for the groups/dataframes that have `0` rows, which doesn't make sense since, by definition, each group have at least one row. So, that's the reason you're getting an empty DataFrame with [`GroupBy.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html).

```
cols = ["cod_tbl", "cod_entry"]

gby = df.groupby(cols).filter(lambda x:len(x)>1)
dup = df[df.duplicated(subset=cols, keep=False)]

gby.equals(dup) # gives True
```

Used input :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"cod_tbl": [100, 200, 100], "cod_entry": [10, 20, 10]})

   cod_tbl  cod_entry
0      100         10
1      200         20
2      100         10
```

Answer (score 0):

**Groupby:** len(x) > 1, not len(x) < 1:

```
gp = df.groupby(['cod_tbl', 'cod_entry']).filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)
```

**Duplicated:** By default, for each set of duplicated values, the first occurrence is set on False and all others on True. By setting keep on "False", all duplicates are True.

```
df.duplicated(subset=['cod_tbl', 'cod_entry'], keep=False)
```

**Ref:** https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html

**Sample Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

# Define the column names
names = ('typ', 'nam_tbl', 'cod_tbl', 'nam_entry', 'cod_entry', 'desc', 'strong')

data = """
A,Table1,100,Entry1,100,Description1,5
B,Table2,200,Entry2,200,Description2,3
C,Table3,200,Entry3,200,Description3,2
D,Table4,400,Entry4,401,Description4,4
E,Table5,500,Entry5,501,Description5,1
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), names=names)

gp = df.groupby(['cod_tbl', 'cod_entry']).filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)
print(gp)

print(df.duplicated(subset=['cod_tbl', 'cod_entry'], keep=False))
```

**Output:**

```
  typ nam_tbl  cod_tbl nam_entry  cod_entry          desc  strong
1   B  Table2      200    Entry2        200  Description2       3
2   C  Table3      200    Entry3        200  Description3       2
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
dtype: bool
```